# $\int_{\partial B_1(0)} \omega f(\omega r) d\omega = 0$ for every $r \ge 0$ implies $\nabla f(0) = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb R^N \to \mathbb R$ be a smooth function and assume that $$\int_{\partial B_1(0)} \omega f(\omega r) d\omega = 0$$ for every $r \ge 0$, where $\partial B_1(0)$ denotes the sphere of unit radius around the origin. Is it then true that $$\nabla f(0) = 0$$
holds?